# Python text processing and text parsing income statements

Tags: python, parsing, text-processing

I would like advice on how to process text from an income statement. I've been trying to use the tables but have found their structure to be too diverse to reliably parse. I would like to instead use text processing, as these reports use the following verbage:

```
Consolidated third quarter net earnings were $72 million, or $0.93 per share
Net loss attributable to common shareholders for the first quarter of 2015 totaled $4.9 million, or $0.02 per basic and diluted share
Non-GAAP Diluted EPS from Continuing Operations of $1.48
Non-GAAP net income per diluted share of $0.44
```

The pattern is pretty obvious, a lot of "net earnings", "per share" and/or "Non-GAAP", but I've never done text processing and am wondering if there is a easy framework I could use make this method easier.

Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I think you are in need of the [standard re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.htmlhttps://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). If you've not used regular expressions before, expect a learning curve.

Comment: I have used re before, but am not a big fan, of course. I will likely end up there though. Thanks.

Comment: check out this site. It is a good tool to use while learning regex. https://regex101.com

Comment: Nice. Yea, I was just on one of the other tester websites. This is coming along nicely. Thanks!

Comment: you can look at the pyparsing https://pyparsing.wikispaces.com module to build parser's which are more readable & less complex than using re